# Help to put Expression equal to zero

Tags: roots

I have this expression
$$g = \sqrt {2\ln {{{\sigma ^2}} \over {{{2r} \over {\sqrt a }}x\log x{e^{ - a{{(r + (1/2){\sigma ^2})}^2}\tau /(2{\sigma ^2})}}}}}.$$

I want to put this expression equal to zero so it would be something like

$$0 = {e^{{{{g^2}} \over 2}}} - { \ldots  \over  \ldots }.$$

${e^{{{{g^2}} \over 2}}}$
I put just to remove squared and $2\ln$ from the right side .

How should I express this correctly?

Comment: Note $g=0 \iff g^2=0 \iff\frac12g^2=0 \iff e^{\frac12g^2}=1$ etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g=\sqrt{2\ln\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\dfrac{2r}{\sqrt{a}}x\log xe^{-a(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)^2\cdot\frac{\tau}{2\sigma^2}}}}\implies e^{\frac{g^2}{2}}=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\dfrac{2r}{\sqrt{a}}x\log xe^{-a(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)^2\cdot\frac{\tau}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ $$\implies e^{\frac{g^2}{2}}-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\dfrac{2r}{\sqrt{a}}x\log xe^{-a(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)^2\cdot\frac{\tau}{2\sigma^2}}}=0$$
If you wanted, $g=0$ instead, then do that and get $e^{\frac{g^2}{2}}=e^0=1$.

Comment: alright you moved the left term over to the right ! thank you,  just one note : $\tau / 2\sigma^{2}$

Comment: fixed. you're right. Could have sworn it was $\sigma^3$.

Comment: yeah it so small font im also having trouble reading it correctly, haha

Answer (score 1):

set the Argument of the logarithm equal to $A$ then we get
$$0=\sqrt{2\ln(A)}$$ from here we get
$$\ln(A)=0=\ln(1)$$ and we get $$A=1$$